# Cross-Entropy Method translation from mathematical notation

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, pseudocode, translate

I want to add the Cross-Entropy method for parameter selection in an algorithm I'm using. The problem is that I don't understand mathematical notation very well and I can't find this version of the cross-entropy method written in code anywhere.

The algorithm, in pseudo code, can be seen in this image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOQtc.png *(I can't paste it here because it has lots of latex)*

It was taken from this paper: https://project.dke.maastrichtuniversity.nl/games/files/phd/Chaslot_thesis.pdf (page 69)

Could you help me translate it into c# or any other language or even into English?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Robert Dodier clarifications, which help me in some ways, but in others made me even more confused,  I went back to a ruby code for the cross entropy method I had seen but thought it wasn't the exact same algorithm I was trying to "translate". With the new found knowledge (from the clarifications) I saw that it was indeed the same algorithm and translated it into c#.

Original ruby code: http://www.cleveralgorithms.com/nature-inspired/probabilistic/cross_entropy.html

My translation into c#:

```
class CrossEntropyMethod
{
    Random r = new Random();
    double objective_function(double[] vector)
    {
        double sum=0f;
        foreach (var f in vector)
        {
            sum+=(double)Math.Pow(f,2);
        }
        return -sum;
    }

    double QuadraticEquation(double[] vector)
    {
        // 5X^2 + 10X - 2 = 0 -> X=-2.183216 || X=0.183216
        double sum = 5 * Math.Pow(vector[0],2) + 10 * vector[0] - 2;
        return - Math.Abs(sum);
    }
    double QuadraticEquation2(double[] vector)
    {
        // 5X^2 + 10X - 2 = 0 -> X=-2.183216 || X=0.183216
        double sum1 = vector[0] * Math.Pow(0.183216, 2) + vector[1] * 0.183216 + vector[2];
        double sum2 = vector[0] * Math.Pow(-2.183216, 2) + vector[1] * -2.183216 + vector[2];
        return - (Math.Abs(sum1) + Math.Abs(sum2));
    }

    double random_variable(double min, double max)
    { 
        return min + ((max - min) * r.NextDouble());
    }

    double random_gaussian(double mean=0.0, double stdev=1.0)
    {
      double u1, u2, w;
      u1 = u2 = w = 0;
      do{
        u1 = 2 * r.NextDouble() - 1;
        u2 = 2 * r.NextDouble() - 1;
        w = u1 * u1 + u2 * u2;
      } while (w >= 1);

      w = Math.Sqrt((-2.0 * Math.Log(w)) / w);
      return mean + (u2 * w) * stdev;
    }

    double[] generate_sample(double[][] search_space, double[] means, double[] stdevs)
    {
      double[] vector = new double[search_space.Length];

          for (int i=0; i<vector.Length; i++)
          {
            vector[i] = random_gaussian(means[i], stdevs[i]);
            vector[i] = Math.Max(vector[i] ,search_space[i][0]);
            vector[i] = Math.Min(vector[i], search_space[i][1]);
        }

      return vector;
    }

    void update_distribution(double[][] samples, double alpha, ref double[] means, ref double[] stdevs)
    {
        for (int i=0; i< means.Length; i++)
        {
            double[] tArray = new double[samples.Length];
            for (int z = 0; z < samples.Length; z++)
            {
                tArray[z] = samples[z][i];
            }
            means[i] = alpha * means[i] + ((1.0 - alpha) * tArray.Average());
            stdevs[i] = alpha * stdevs[i] + ((1.0 - alpha) * MyExtensions.StandardDeviation(tArray));
        }
    }

    double[] search(double[][] bounds, int max_iter, int num_samples, int num_update, double learning_rate)
    {
        double[] means = new double[bounds.Length];
        double[] stdevs = new double[bounds.Length];
        for (int i=0; i< means.Count(); i++)
        {
            means[i]=random_variable(bounds[i][0], bounds[i][1]);
            stdevs[i]=bounds[i][1]-bounds[i][0];
        }
        double[] best=null;
        double bestScore=double.MinValue;
        for (int t=0; t<max_iter; t++)
        {
            double[][] samples= new double[num_samples][];
            double[] scores=new double[num_samples];
            for (int s=0; s<num_samples; s++)
            {
                samples[s]=generate_sample(bounds, means, stdevs);
                scores[s]=QuadraticEquation(samples[s]);
            }
            Array.Sort(scores,samples);
            Array.Reverse(scores);
            Array.Reverse(samples);
            if (best==null || scores.First() > bestScore)
            {
                bestScore=scores.First();
                best=samples.First();
            }
            double[][] selected = new double[num_update][];
            Array.Copy(samples,selected,num_update);
            update_distribution(selected, learning_rate, ref means, ref stdevs);
            Console.WriteLine("iteration={0}, fitness={1}", t, bestScore);
        }
      return best;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        double[][] parameters = new double[][] { new double[] { -500, 500 }}; //QuadraticEquation parameters
        //double[][] parameters = new double[][] { new double[] { 4, 6 }, new double[] { 9, 11 }, new double[] { -3, -1} }; //QuadraticEquation2 parameters
        //double[][] parameters = new double[][] { new double[] { -5, 5 }, new double[] { -5, 5 }, new double[] { -5, 5 } }; //object_function parameters
        int maxIter = 100;
        int nSamples = 50;
        int nUpdate = 5;
        double alpha = 1;
        double[] best = search(parameters, maxIter, nSamples, nUpdate, alpha);
        string str = string.Join(" | ", best.Select(a => a.ToString("N10")).ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine("Best: " + str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, their notation isn't the clearest, but I'll try to explain the bits that might be confusing. I assume the loops and assignments aren't any problem for you.

- Variables in bold font are vector values; same names in ordinary font are a single element of the vector.
- (bold x) raised to (i) is the i'th value of (bold x). Note that (bold x) is a vector of length m (where m = number of dimensions in which you're working), and there are N such vectors, so i runs from 1 to N.
- (mu sub j) prime is a new value of (mu sub j), i.e., the prime is not differentiation or anything else. Likewise (sigma^2 sub j) prime.
- (bold x - mu)^T (bold x - mu) is the inner product, a.k.a. scalar product. Note that a^T b is just (sum over k) a[k] b[k]. They could have written out the summation but it's a conventional shorthand to write a^T b. (The superscript T is supposed to mean matrix transpose but it's applied in situations in which the transpose itself doesn't matter, just the implied summation.)
- Centered dot represents scalar multiplication.

Hope this is enough to get you going. Feel free to follow up with any questions.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I really need this and didn't have a clue how to translate that. You answer helped to clarify somethings but there are still others i don't understand: 1. How should I initialize mu and sigma2? 2. What is Gauss raised to m? 3. How am I suposed to evaluate x raised to i in my evaluation function if x(i) apparently is composed of mu and sigma2? (my evaluation function needs to receive the parameters the algorithm suggests as the best ones) 4. Is E_something normal e function? Thanks again for the help!!

Comment: 6. What exactly is the sub j? Is j=t? I've seen you code in python. I do code in python too. Could you translate that algorithm (without the minute details, like scalar multiplications and simple stuff) into something python-readable? That would help a lot!

Comment: (1) initial values might or might not make a difference (depending on presence or absence of local maxima of the goodness of fit). That said, I'd take initial mu = all zeros and initial sigma = all ones. (2) Gauss^m = m-dimensional Gaussian (i.e. normal) distribution. The covariance seems to be described by a vector, not a matrix, so I guess that the different dimensions are independent and therefore Gauss^m = (1-d Gauss) times (1-d Gauss) ... (m times). (3) x superscript (i) is an index, not an exponent. (Yes, that's f*cked up.) (4) E_{t+1} is a set (namely righthand side of assignment).

Comment: @joaoroque (6) Looks like j indexes dimensions 1 to m (not t). When they say mu_j := ..., there is an implied for-loop for j=1 to m. Sorry, I can't translate the code to Python today. HTH all the same.

Comment: Thanks for the help! You assumed I was at least somewhat good at math, when I'm only half bad. But if it wasn't for your help I probably wouldn't have been able to solve this! Thanks :)

Comment: @joaoroque I'm glad to help. Glad to hear that you got it worked out after all.